# Temperature sensor MLX90614 read object temperature above 300°C

Tags: sensors, esp8266

I want to make sure the sensor read normally but when i run it to read the object temperature, the result is 382.19°C. I have search for tutorials, and also the error but i couldn't find it except for emissivity. The board I am using right now is ESP8266 Nodemcu Lolin

And this is the code

```
#define INTERVAL  1000
#include <Wire.h>
#include <IR_Thermometer_Sensor_MLX90614.h>



IR_Thermometer_Sensor_MLX90614 mlx = IR_Thermometer_Sensor_MLX90614();


float T_ambient,T_object;
unsigned long int timer;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  mlx.begin(); 
}

void loop()
{
  if(millis()-timer>=INTERVAL)
  {
    timer=millis();
    T_ambient=mlx.GetAmbientTemp_Celsius();
    T_object=mlx.GetObjectTemp_Celsius();

    Serial.println("Ambien = "+String (T_ambient));
    Serial.println("Object = " +String (T_object));
  }
  delay(1);
}
```

[image]

Thank You

Comment: This is typically the sign that there’s a communication problem. Either there is a physical wiring issue, or you are not using the right pins. How is the sensor connected, and what pins are you using?

Comment: Hi @jcaron, the pin i am using right now is scl to d1, sda to d2, vin to 3v3 and gnd to gnd

Comment: Did you check if you sensor is a 3.3V version and not a 5V version? This is defined by the first letter after "SF" in the reference (A=5V, B=3V). Even though the pins you use should be the default for for an ESP8266 Nodemcu, you may want to specify them explicitly. Also, is the sensor brand new, or is it possible someone changed the address or other settings?

Comment: Actually, communication is probably functional, the sensor is just returning the max possible value for the object temp most of the time (but not always). I'd still check for a possible voltage issue.

Comment: It seems to get you the right ambient temperature ? What is the object temperature you're expecting ? Do you have some other measurement device to confirm/refute the 382C reading ?

Comment: @kalyanswaroop the log shows that the object temperature goes back and forth between exactly the same as ambient and the maximum value. I suppose OP would know if the err was a >300°C heat source around… I think the sensor is acting weirdly, which could be due to an inadequate power supply. Or it could simply be faulty, of course.

Comment: Hi @jcaron, thank you for your response. Sorry that i cant response fast enough. The nodemcu i bought is new and also the sensor is. Can you tell me more about checking the voltage issue? Sorry I am new to this part.

Comment: Hi @kalyanswaroop, the object I try to scan is the just random object like smartphone, my hand, pencils, and other random object. But when I try to scan the object from scanning air, the temperature always go above 300°C. And i don't have the device to confirm my measurement to confirm the temperature.

Comment: Maybe a bad sensor or it is being affected by power noise. Try putting a ceramic 0.1 micro farad capacitor close to the Vin and gnd pins. Else, perhaps you have a bad sensor or a wrongly configured one.

Comment: Also, see if the emissivity is set wrong. Add this line to the setup after the mlx.begin().  mlx.writeEmissivity(0.95) or maybe try mlx.writeEmissivity(1.0)

Comment: @kalyanswaroop When i the mlx.writeEmissivity(0.95), i got the error 'class IR_Thermometer_Sensor_MLX90614' has no member named 'wireEmissivity'

Comment: And i also try to add a pull up resistor with 10k value but the result is still the same

Comment: please try writeEmissivity instead of wireEmissivity